# Angular 14 - proxy.config.json not working properly

Tags: angular, http, proxy, angular-cli

My proxy.config.json of my angular application worked normally and stopped working after upgrading to angular 14

The application use proxy when running on localhost to avoid CORS policy problem.
The console log shows that the proxy is active and the request is being rewritten, but the http request does not change and error 404 not found occurs. I would like help to make the proxy work

In the command line I start the application like this

```
ng serve --verbose --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

Command prompt log shows as below indicating proxy is active

```
√ Compiled successfully.
    [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/<resource-path>" to "/myapp/<resource-path>"
    [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] GET /api/<resource-path> ~> http://localhost:8888
```

But when making the call http://localhost:4200/api/, apparently the proxy does not act and error 404 not found occurs

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/<resource-path> 404 (Not Found)
[webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/<resource-path>', ok: false, …}
```

The http request is being made like this

```
        this.http.get<TO>('/api/<resource-path>', { headers: new HttpHeaders() })
           .subscribe(result => {
            this.result = result;
        });
```

But httpclient transforms to

```
http://localhost:4200/api/<resource-path>
```

proxy.config.json

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8888",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": "/myapp"
          },
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.11.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "angular-imask": "^6.4.2",
    "ngx-mask": "^14.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.13",
    "angular-crud": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "180kb",
                  "maximumError": "180kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "myapp"
}
```

Comment: “But when making the call http://localhost:4200/api/,…” - you should make a relative call, so just /api…

Comment: I verified that the http request is being made like this /api/<resource-path>, but httpclient transforms to http://localhost:4200/api/<resource-path>

Comment: @araraujo have you find any solution to this problem i'm having the same problem

Comment: @araraujo how you got web-server logs?